# Is it possible show progress of bytes transferred when uploading photos

Tags: facebook, upload, photo, progress

Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Below is what I am using to Construct the request and it is working fine.
Request(Session session, String graphPath, Bundle parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Callback callback)

Is it possible to show progress during the process? At the moment I am showing an indeterminate progress bar and then hide it when the request is completed in the Callback's onCompleted method.

I did a search and the nearest I found is modifying the Util.java file but it is noted that the CLASS SHOULD BE CONSIDERED DEPRECATED.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to do the same thing. I haven't started digging in much, but my first guess would be to modify the `Request` class, and specifically the `newUploadPhotoRequest(...)` method.